# find column value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

Have 2 dataframes. 
First has 1 column.

`test1: 1,2,3,4,5`

Second has 2 columns.

`test2: 0 1 1 1 1. test3: 2 2 3 3 4`

I need to create new column in First dataframe that with search row value exist in whole dataframe2 (simple ctrl+F). 
As result I need to get
test1: 1,2,3,4,5
check: yes,yes,yes,yes,no

UPD
Below code I found, but it shows good result only for first row, don't know if that make sense

```
first['check'] = second.eq(first['test1'],0).any(1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `isin` with values flatten

```
test1['col2']=test1['col1'].isin(test2.values.ravel())
```

Comment: Using code First['col2']=First['test1'].isin(Second.values.reavel().tolist()) I have error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'reavel'

Comment: I think `tolist` here is not necessary

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'test1': [1,2,3,4,5]})
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test2': [0,1,1,1,1], 'test3': [2,2,3,3,4]})

In [2]: df1
Out[2]:
   test1
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5

In [3]: df2
Out[3]:
   test2  test3
0      0      2
1      1      2
2      1      3
3      1      3
4      1      4

In [4]: df1['check'] = df1['test1'].isin(df2['test2']) \
   ...:                | df1['test1'].isin(df2['test3'])
   ...: df1
Out[4]:
   test1  check
0      1   True
1      2   True
2      3   True
3      4   True
4      5  False
```